# Why does NLog LogManager return null for Release build, but works fine for Debug?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, nlog

I have a line of code as below:

```
LoggingConfiguration config = LogManager.Configuration;
```

When I run this in Debug build, it's fine the config is returned. When I run it in Release build it throws an exception, which I tracked down to this call returning null.

I unzipped both APK's and can see the NLog.config file in the asset folder. 
I also wrote some code that explicitly loads the file and outputs it to Console.Writeline and it works in both Debug and Release builds.

I've added a null check but I do actually want to modify the NLog config and do some logging when this code is called.

Nuget package info on NLog:

```
<package id="NLog.Config" version="4.4.3" targetFramework="monoandroid41" />
```

I tested the app via the Windows version (Xamarin.Windows so some shared code). Found logging works just fine in Release mode.

I worked out how to get NLog to log to its internal logfile (had to use an explicit path to a location it had permission to write to).

```
internalLogToConsole ="true" internalLogLevel="Trace" internalLogFile="/storage/sdcard0/Download/nlog-internal.log">
```

The error logged when built and run in Release mode is:

```
Error Parsing configuration from assets/NLog.config failed. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Exception when parsing assets/NLog.config. --> NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Cannot access the constructor of type: NLog.Targets.FileTarget. Is the required permission granted?
```

I unzipped the Release APK and can see the NLog.config file in the asset folder. I'm wondering how you would modify the permissions to this file. Also why is it fine in Debug build but not in Release build?

Comment: There is no way to answer that question because it is all up to the programmer. Sure there are some *technical* differences as well but in context of your question, to explain why the configuration is there in debug but not in release, you'll have to consult the code.

Comment: There are so many options... one of them being, you could have config transformation files for each build target.

Comment: Could you reproduce this on your local (Windows) machine?

Comment: Not checked, but worth investigating tomorrow.  Thanks

Comment: I've upgraded to NLog 4.4.9 and turned off optimisation as well as set Linking to None. This issue no longer seems to be happening. I'm not sure which of these changes has affected the behaviour. 
I turned off optimisation because it was removing code that it thought was not being used (except it was). Not had time to troubleshoot the answer for this question.